# How to get ServerWorld to spawn my entity through code?

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I need to summon my entity inside a block when i press a button.

I have an entity: MarkEntity

I have a key to press : B on keyboard

I need to get ServerWorld to call world.spawnEntity(myEntity) inside my method.

My classes:

```java
public class MarkRaycast {

    private static MinecraftClient CLIENT = MinecraftClient.getInstance();

    public static void MakeAMark(){
        var hit = CLIENT.crosshairTarget;
        var hitType = hit.getType();
        ExampleMod.LOGGER.info(hit.getType().toString());

        if(hitType == HitResult.Type.BLOCK){
            SummonEntity.Mark(hit.getPos()); // call to summon here
        }

    }
}
```

```java
public class SummonEntity {
    public static void Mark(Vec3d crd){

        ServerWorld world; // HERE i need to get server world somehow.

        var entityType = (EntityType<MarkEntity>) EntityType.get("example:mark").get();
        MarkEntity customEntity = entityType.create(world);

        customEntity.updatePosition(crd.x, crd.y, crd.z);

        var result = world.spawnEntity(customEntity);
        ExampleMod.LOGGER.info("Result : " + result);
    }
}
```

I need to spawn an entity inside a block on which i look by pressing a B button. It should looks like on the picture.[the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX9fS.jpg)